# Sig Figs, Combined Operations

Tags: conventions, notation, error-analysis

Using the sig fig rule for addition / subtraction seems to break in certain circumstances.

For example (I'm using underlines to show sig figs):

$\underline{66}+\underline{66}-\underline{1.3}\times 10^2=$

We need to convert them all to the same power of 10:

$0.\underline{66}\times 10^2+0.\underline{66}\times 10^2-\underline{1.3}\times 10^2=0.\underline{0}2\times 10^2 \Rightarrow 0\times 10^1$

We start with 3 values with 2 sig figs, and end up with -1 sig fig, which would be rounded to... 0ish?

Is there some better way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

When adding/subtracting, the final number should have the same number of significant figures after the decimal point as the number with the least amount of digits after its decimal point.

Instead of converting every value to the same power of ten, line up each of the decimal points. So, convert 66 to 6.6$\times10^1$, or you could also convert 1.3$\times10^2$ to 13$\times10^1$. When the decimal places are lined up, you add the values together, then cut off whatever comes after the lowest number of digits after the decimal point required by the addition/subtraction rule mentioned above. In the first case, there should be one digit after the decimal point, so you should end up with an answer of 2.0. In the second case, since none of the values have significant figures after the decimal point, the result would just be 2.

Comment: First of all, you say "instead of converting every value to the same power of 10," and then you do exactly that, just a different one. Plus, in your example, 13x10^1, has 0 sig figs after the decimal place, so the final answer of 0.2x10^1, would still be 0 by your method, which is exactly what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong; the answer is essentially $0$, and there is no conservation of significant figures whatsoever when adding. The crux of the calculation is
\begin{align}
& \underline{132} \\
- & \underline{13}0 \\ \hline
& \phantom{0}\underline{0}2
\end{align}
In other words, $(132\pm1) - (130\pm10) = 2\pm10$. But as long as we are using significant figures to treat errors the quick and dirty way, we're not going to distinguish between $2\pm10$ and $0\pm10$ -- they're both about as good, and the latter maintains the convention with significant figures of rounding to the nearest multiple of the uncertainty.

The only issue is that just writing "$0$" implies $0\pm1$ if anything at all. The only way to preserve the magnitude of the uncertainty with significant figures when the answer is $0$ is to explicitly report it as e.g. "$0\pm10$." This really should be done, since the whole point of significant figures is to convey *some* sense of uncertainty in a compact way. Even if you went with $2$ as the answer you couldn't write "$2$" (which stands for $2\pm1$), but would have to write "$2\pm10$."

Significant figures aren't perfect. After all, they're just a simplistic method used only in school to prevent students from copying all 16 digits from their calculator's display (and believing those numbers mean anything!).

Comment: That's what I was thinking. So this is just a case of where the sig fig rules kind of break down?